# SQLException: executeQuery method can not be used for update

Tags: java, mysql, sql, servlets

I am trying to insert user information taken from a registration form into Derby DB using a java servlet class.

I get connected to the DB on NetBeans right after the user clicks the submit button with the user's information filled out. Then it should run this method:

```
public void insertNewUser(String userName, String passWord, String lastName, String firstName, String age, char sex, String email) {
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String insertNewUserSQL = "INSERT INTO " + studentsTable + " VALUES ('" + userName + "', '" + passWord + "', '" + lastName + "', '" + firstName + "', " + age + ", '" + sex + "', '" + email + "')";
        System.out.println(insertNewUserSQL);
        stmt.executeQuery(insertNewUserSQL);
        stmt.close();
    } catch(SQLException sqlExcept) {
        sqlExcept.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I keep getting the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: executeQuery method can not be used for update.
```

What does this mean exactly?

The SQL command is correct as I can do it manually on NetBeans SQL Command window.

Are there restrictions for servlets or something I don't know about?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since you are inserting a record, you should be using `executeUpdate()` not `executeQuery()`.

Here are some methods that are usually misused:

---

boolean execute()

> Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which may
>   be any kind of SQL statement.

ResultSet executeQuery()

> Executes the SQL query in this PreparedStatement object and returns
>   the ResultSet object generated by the query.

**int executeUpdate()**

> Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which
>   must be an SQL INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement; or an SQL statement
>   that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.

---

One more thing, your query is weak as it is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`. Please do parameterized by using `PreparedStatement`.

Sample Code Snippet:

```
String insertNewUserSQL = "INSERT INTO " + studentsTable + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(insertNewUserSQL);
pstmt.setString(1, userName);
// ... repeat this step until the last parameter ....
pstmt.setString(7, email);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

- [Java PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Answer (score 1):

To update values you need to use an updatable ResultSet, as follows:

```
ResultSet res = preparedStatement.executeQuery(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
res.first();
res.updateInt("id", 2);
res.updateRow();
```

Alternatively, you can use the executeUpdate method of statement, as follows:
`statement.executeUpdate("update table set id = 2");`