# How to update Tables with an input from the user

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

So here is the thing, I am trying to update my table, update the `exam` mark where the `student` value is entered by the user.

So I am using this query.

```
updateExamMark = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE Results SET exam= ? WHERE student = ?");
```

And this is my methods (not complete code)

```
public List< Results > updateExamMark( int exam, String student )
 {
  List< Results > results = null;
  ResultSet resultSet = null;

  try 
  {
      updateExamMark.setInt(1, exam ); 
      updateExamMark.setString(2, student);


     // executeQuery returns ResultSet containing matching entries
     resultSet = updateExamMark.executeQuery(); 

     results = new ArrayList< Results >();
```

I am getting this error "Execute query method cannot be used to update"

What is wrong with my query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006868/sqlexception-executequery-method-can-not-be-used-for-update did you checked this

Comment: it says exactly what it means "Execute query method cannot be used to update"

Answer (score 1):

> Execute query method cannot be used to update

```
resultSet = updateExamMark.executeQuery();
```

Change to

```
int r = updateExamMark.executeUpdate();
```

You should use `executeUpdate()` to execute non-select queries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `executeQuery()` to `executeUpdate()`, as the first method is used to execute `SELECT` queries. When you need to update (`INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`...) you have to use the second one.

So the statement

```
resultSet = updateExamMark.executeQuery();
```

would return you all the results of a `SELECT` statement into `resultSet`. Change this statement to

```
int rowsAffected = updateExamMark.executeUpdate();
```

which will return you the number of rows affected by your update.