# Insert into Database using javafx not working properly

Tags: java, spring, javafx

i m new in javafx so please excuse my silly mistake i had created a registration fxml using javafx but when i try to store data its will allways throw it into catch block of my modelcontroller where i have a insert query for sql

here is My RegistrationController

```
        public void Registersign(ActionEvent event){
        try {
        String Fname=fname.getText();
        String Lname=lname.getText();
        String Email=email.getText();
        String TXTusr=txtUser.getText();
        String TXTpass=txtPass.getText();
        String TXTPassconf=txtPassconf.getText();if(Fname.isEmpty()||Lname.isEmpty()||Email.isEmpty()||TXTusr.isEmpty()||TXTpass.isEmpty()){

                Alert alert=new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                alert.setHeaderText(null);
                alert.setContentText("Please Fill All DATA");
                alert.showAndWait();
                return;

        }
            loginModel.isRegister(TXTusr,TXTpass, Fname,Lname, Email);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

here is my modelcontroller to insert my registration data into database

```
          public void isRegister(String user,String pass,String firstname,String lastname,String email) throws SQLException
{
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement=null;
    ResultSet resultSet=null;
      String sql = "INSERT INTO login (username, password, firstname,lastname, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?,?, ?)";
      try {
    preparedStatement=Con.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, user);
    preparedStatement.setString(2, pass);
    preparedStatement.setString(3, firstname);
    preparedStatement.setString(4, lastname);
    preparedStatement.setString(5, email);
     resultSet=preparedStatement.executeQuery();


        System.out.println("A new user was inserted successfully!");


} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
       System.out.println("A new user was insertion failed!");
}
```

it allways throw at catch block in modelContoller i had check it through debugger

Comment: Please, post the stack trace of the exception to get some help.

Comment: Maybe @Usagi is right See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006868/sqlexception-executequery-method-can-not-be-used-for-update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `executeUpdate()` instead of `executeQuery()` if using non-`SELECT` SQL statement.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate--